# Unit testing .NET DateTime to SQL DateTime values

Tags: .net, sql-server, unit-testing, datetime

When I run this code:

```
var data = "test";
var timestamp = DateTime.Now;
var id = repo.InsertNewRecord(data, timestamp);
var record = repo.GetRecord(id);

Assert.AreEqual(data, record.Data);
Assert.AreEqual(timestamp, record.TimeStamp);
```

... it fails on the second assertion.

The expected timestamp has a tick count of 635449135145624472, but the value I'm receiving from the database has a tick count of 635449135140000000.  This is understandable because .NET DateTime values have an accuracy of 100ns while SQL Server DateTime only has a accuracy of 3.33ms.  I don't really need to be the timestamps to be more accurate than that, but is there a standard way of testing the inputs and outputs for equality?

Obtaining a timestamp from the database is one way to do it:

```
var timestamp = Session.CreateSQLQuery("SELECT GetDate()").UniqueResult<DateTime>();
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't test at tick level, you could use a particular format to test the dates e.g.

```
var dateFmt = "dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss";
Assert.AreEqual(timestamp.ToString(dateFmt), record.TimeStamp.ToString(dateFmt));
```

Or alternatively, you *could* do that but just add some room for variance

```
Assert.True((timeStamp - record.TimeStamp).TotalMilliseconds < 1000);
```